# Is it possible to create a select statement with the result of another select statement?

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery

Is it possible to create a select statement with the result of another select statement?

Important is, that Table2 can have a different number of columns.

Example:

```
Table1: 
+------+------+
| colA | colB | 
+------+------+
| colE |   0  | 
| colF |   0  | 
+--------+----+

Table2:
+------+------+------+
| colE | colF | colG |
+------+------+------+
|   1  |   1  |   1  |
|   1  |   1  |   1  |
+------+------+------+

select colA from Table1 where colB = '0';  
Result:
colE
colF
```

and now I want to sum all values of the columns in Table2 where the column names are the same as in the result above (sum of all values of colE and colF). The result should be 4 in this case.

I use mariaDB.

Comment: You can either hardcode the values (if you know all of them) or use dynamic SQL.

Comment: You need to normalize your tables. Read this article: https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff and how can I do that with dynamic SQL? hardcode is not an option the table can be different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dynamic SQL along with `information_schema.columns` table, which provides information about columns in tables, in order to derive the columns of the `Table2`by joining to the `Table1` to get only matching columns such as

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('SUM(',colA,')') SEPARATOR '+' )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT t1.colA 
           FROM( SELECT *
                   FROM information_schema.columns
                  WHERE table_name = 'Table2' ) AS c
           JOIN Table1 AS t1
             ON t1.colA = c.column_name ) AS t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',@sql,'  AS total FROM Table2'); 
                  
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=689005296c4b6d195c6c06e2aea1fd5c)</kbd>